# Start:stop slicing inconsistencies between numpy and Pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am a bit suprised/confused about the following difference between numpy and Pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.random.randn(10,10)

> a[:3,0, newaxis]

array([[-1.91687144],
       [-0.6399471 ],
       [-0.10005721]])
```

However:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(a)

> b.ix[:3,0]

0   -1.916871
1   -0.639947
2   -0.100057
3    0.251988
```

In other words, numpy does not include the `stop` index in `start:stop` notation, but Pandas does. I thought Pandas was based on Numpy. Is this a bug? Intentional?

Comment: Why are you using `b.ix` instead of just `b[:3]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *is* documented, and it's part of [Advanced Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-advanced). The key here is that you're not using a stop index at all.

The `ix` attribute is a special thing that lets you do various kinds of advanced indexing *by label*—choosing a list of labels, using an inclusive range of labels instead of a half-exclusive range of indices, and various other things.

If you don't want that, just don't use it:

```
In [191]: b[:3][0]
Out[191]: 
0   -0.209386
1    0.050345
2    0.318414
Name: 0
```

If you play with this a bit more without reading the docs, you'll probably come up with a case where your labels are, say, `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'` instead of `0, 1, 2, 3`, and suddenly, `b.ix[:3]` will returns only 3 rows instead of 4, and you'll be baffled all over again.

The difference is that in that case, `b.ix[:3]` is a slice on *indices*, not on *labels*.

What you've requested in your code is actually ambiguous between "all labels up to an including 3" and "all indices up to but not including 3", and labels always win with `ix` (because if you don't want label slicing, you don't have to use `ix` in the first place). And that's why I said the problem is that you're not using a stop index at all.

Comment: In your example though, it returns a copy. You would need to use .loc or .iloc for assignment right?

Answer (score 2):

When the index type is integer, `DataFrame.ix` will use label-based indexing only. According to the document, label based slice will include start and stop.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-labels

> Slicing with labels is semantically slightly different because the
>   slice start and stop are inclusive in the label-based case.
>
> Label-based indexing with integer axis labels is a thorny topic. It
>   has been discussed heavily on mailing lists and among various members
>   of the scientific Python community. In pandas, our general viewpoint
>   is that labels matter more than integer locations. Therefore, with an
>   integer axis index only label-based indexing is possible with the
>   standard tools like .ix. The following code will generate exceptions

Answer (score 1):

From ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-labels)):

> Slicing has standard Python semantics for integer slices
>
> ...
>
> Slicing with labels is semantically slightly different because the
>   slice start and stop are inclusive in the label-based case.

Comment: Right, but how can you make label-based slicing exclusive at one end (like normal python slicing!)