# Matricial (positional) indexing of DataFrames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
tmp = np.random.randn(10,4)
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, index=pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=tmp.shape[0]), 
                 columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

> b
                   A         B         C         D
2012-01-01  0.471846  1.130041 -0.614117  0.882738
2012-01-02 -1.431566  0.680617 -0.615331  0.288740
2012-01-03  0.398567 -0.115388 -0.869855 -1.273666
2012-01-04  0.379501  0.192329 -1.942184  0.694004
2012-01-05  1.306329 -0.803856  0.417033 -0.655907
2012-01-06 -0.599877  0.696549 -0.252789  1.367977
2012-01-07 -1.618916  0.216571 -0.499880  0.386853
2012-01-08  0.415002  0.139775  0.251842  0.021379
2012-01-09  2.536787  0.737672 -0.740485 -0.890189
2012-01-10 -1.553530 -0.100950 -0.237478 -0.295612
```

How can I do:

1. Positional indexing of specific rows/columns? (and get the corresponding sub-**dataframe**)
2. Positional indexing of ranges of rows/columns? (and get the corresponding sub-**dataframe**)

### For single-entry matricial indexing:

For example, say I want to index the sub-dataframe in location `[1,2]` (in numpy "matricial" notation). The output should be:

```
                   C
2012-01-02 -0.615331
```

I tried the following three methods, but none of them worked::

```
df[1,2]
df[1][2]
df.take([1])[2]
```

The only methods that work seem to be:

```
df.ix[1,2]
df.irow(1)[2]
```

but:

- Using `.ix` for positional indexing is dangerous, since it would default to **label indexing** if my indices were integers (as opposed to dates as in the case above). See more on this here: [Start:stop slicing inconsistencies between numpy and Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125961/startstop-slicing-inconsistencies-between-numpy-and-pandas).
- Using `irow` is cumbersome, since it requires switching from `()` notation to `[]`notation (`irow` returns a `Series` object)

### For range matricial indexing:

For example, say I want to index elements in locations `[1:3,2:3]` in (numpy matricial notation). The output should be:

```
                   B
2012-01-02 -0.615331  
2012-01-03 -0.869855
```

Note that I am **excluding** the **stop indices** (i.e. I am sticking to the numpy notation).

Any thoughts?

Comment: What about something like this? `df.as_matrix()[1:3,2:3]`.  Do you need the result to retain all of DataFrame meta information?

Comment: Thanks @Zelazny7. That's great, but yes, I would really like to retain the DataFrame meta information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this often requested feature will shortly be in place
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/2922
u can pull it off of the branch if u would like to test with it

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround (until the feature request @Jeff mentioned gets committed):

```
In [178]: df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, index=pd.date_range('2012-1-1', periods=tmp.shape[0]), columns='A B C D'.split())

In [179]: df.ix[df.index[1], df.columns[2]]
Out[179]: -0.3021434106214243

In [180]: df.ix[df.index[1:3], df.columns[2:3]]
Out[180]: 
                   C
2012-01-02 -0.302143
2012-01-03 -1.430387
```

This shows the syntax works the same way even with shuffled integer indices:

```
In [206]: df2 = df.reset_index(drop=True)

In [207]: index = range(10)

In [208]: import random

In [209]: random.shuffle(index)

In [210]: df2.index = index

In [212]: df2.ix[df2.index[1], df2.columns[2]]
Out[212]: -0.3021434106214243

In [213]: df2.ix[df2.index[1:3], df2.columns[2:3]]
Out[213]: 
          C
7 -0.302143
2 -1.430387
```

Comment: .ix is the right solution, since your frame does not have any ambiguities in the indexing scheme, using integers WILL react how you expect it, eg positional indexing via numpy/python semantics (its only when u have an index that is itself made up of integers where this is a problem)

Answer (score 0):

from the pandas documentation:

Pandas provides a suite of methods in order to get purely integer based indexing. The semantics follow closely python and numpy slicing. These are 0-based indexing. When slicing, the start bounds is included, while the upper bound is excluded. Trying to use a non-integer, even a valid label will raise a IndexError.

The .iloc attribute is the primary access method. The following are valid inputs:

An integer e.g. 5
A list or array of integers [4, 3, 0]
A slice object with ints 1:7